# What are the differences between Listener and High-Order functions in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Please explain a use cases and pros and cons of each approach.

1. Use of interface.

   ```
   fun doSomethingWithCallback(callback: Callback) {
       // Do something
       callback.call()
   }
   ```
2. Use of high-order function.

   ```
   fun doSomethingWithCallback(callback: () -> Unit) {
       // Do something
       callback()
   }
   ```

Comment: Ooooor you can use a high-order function with a typealias! `typealias Callback = () -> Unit`

Comment: typealias is just an alternative name, right? what difference does it make to approach?

Comment: Great! But with interface you can pass only it's implementation, but with high-order function there is no such limitation.

Comment: Nah. Every function that matches the input-output of the method is a valid "implementation". You can even use a function reference `::someFunction`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Option 1

With **option 1** you're not able to call it passing a lambda. For example this does not compile:

```
doSomethingWithCallback1 { print("helloWorld") }
```

Interestingly if the same method were defined in Java:

```
void doSomethingWithJavaCallback(JavaCallback callback) {
    // Do something
    callback.call();
}
```

Then **you can call it using a lambda** from Kotlin. This is because  Kotlin only does SAM-conversion for functions defined in Java.

### Option 2

In contrast if you go with **option 2** you do get to call it using a lambda. And it will work both when calling it from Kotlin and from Java.

### Option 3

As mentioned in the comments a **third option** is using a type alias like this:

```
typealias Callback = () -> Unit

fun doSomethingWithCallback5(callback: Callback) {
    // Do something
    callback()
}
```

You get to keep the type in the function signature **and** use lambdas on the call site.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use with a lambda :

   ```
      doSomethingWithCallback { // do whatever you want }
   ```
2. I usually use lambda function by this one:

   `var doSomething: ((Any) -> Unit)? = null`

and invoke callback:

```
    doSomething?.invoke(any)
```

finally as same as listener:

```
    youClass.doSomething = { any ->
        // this is callback
    }
```

Comment: First option cannot be used with lambda

Comment: Are you missing a (   ???
var doSomething: ((Any) -> Unit)? = null